# grant write permissions to user on a directory centos

Tags: permissions, centos

So I did this

```
sudo chown -R user1:user1 /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

and

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www
```

but apparently when php wants to write a file on public_html folder
I get an error saying " failed to open stream: Permission denied "

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is php running as `user1`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In fact I was misguided and used my username to chown the directory when instead I should have used nginx, beacuse that's what I'm running.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you instead create a groups as shown below:

```
groupadd mygroup
```

where `mygroup` is the group name.

Then you add the user to the group:

```
usermod -aG mygroup user1
```

where `user1` is the user who will be accessing.

After that, you can then assign the directory to the group using this command:

```
chgrp mygroup /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

Once done you can now assign permissions to the folder using this command;

```
chmod -R 0760  /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

Please note that `0760` is an example, you can give appropriate permissions as required